# UIButton not showing on real device while running on Xcode8

Tags: ios10, xcode8, swift2

Today i run my project on Xcode8. Before that it was executed good and shown all button properly. when i run project on xcode8 simulator and device. few buttons not visible on run time but action performing.

Please assist me on this issue.

Comment: Having same issue. Have you figured this out?

Comment: Having same issue. Try to debug the issue. When I did, I found the frame as this UIButton: 0x7fe3885f6560; frame = (0 0; 1000 1000)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, There are some problems in Xcode 8 compiler.
I were having such issue, i have resolved by doing following things

1. If i have done anyoperation on layer(cornerRadius,bordering,masksToBounds etc.) in `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear`/`awakeFromNib` then move them to either `layoutSubViews` method or `viewDidAppear` method.
2. If I have set left/right view in textfield, then move it also to `viewDidAppear` or `layoutSubviews`.
3. Try most of UI Related operation in `viewDidAppear` or `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Bummer with Xcode8. why they changed like this. i will check it out. Thanks man